# What kind of index will help speed up my join?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two table, *meta* (a small table) and *metastatus* (a huge table). I have index on the *ipaddr* column which I will use to join them.

My query is

```
select m.ipaddr, m.machineclass
from meta m
join metastatus s on s.ipaddr = m.ipaddr
where m.machineclass = 'atm'
limit 1000;
```

And here's the [plan](http://explain.depesz.com/s/3ML).

Clearly the *ipaddr* index on *metastatus* is not used. I would like to get some recommendation. Will adding index in this situation helps? Or what can I do to speed up the query?

**UPDATE**: the *ipaddr* index on *metastatus* is a **clustered index**. I think this matters?

Comment: Your stats seem to be way off.  Analyze the tables and see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it has anything to do with your index being clustered or not.

For this query to work efficiently, you should create compound index `(machineclass, ipaddr)` in `meta` table:

```
CREATE INDEX meta_machineclass_ipaddr_idx (machineclass, ipaddr);
```

This should work well as long as machineclass=`'atm'` has high selectivity (or less than 10% of all rows are `'atm'` class).

Comment: but I think the problem is that it is not using the index on *metastatus*

Comment: I assume that index on metastatus(ipaddr) exists? Nevertheless, try this - it should help

Answer (score 0):

your meta table should have an index on (machineclass) to qualify your where clause.  meta status should  have on (ipaddr) as you already indicated.

Comment: yes, I already have an index on *machineclass* :) I should have mentioned that.

Comment: Index on machineclass only will not change anything

Comment: @mvp, vs no index?  It ABSOLUTELY WILL help the query for that index.  Take it out of the context of his table being a smaller set... but say even 10,000 records vs millions.  Someone else not knowing where to begin knowing that index based on where criteria will always help.